# Spring - unable to log request body in custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor implementation class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, interceptor

I have created a class name as `HttpInterceptor` which implements `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. The purpose of this class is to intercept the `resttemplate` calls, then override the intercept method. During execution, I am unable to log the request body. However, there is a request body which is sent from the front end.

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

    String requestBody = "";
    String url = request.getURI().toString();

    ClientHttpResponse response = null;
    Date timeIn = new Date();
    String responseBody = "";

    // I have also try new String(body, "UTF-8") and many others.
    requestBody = new String(body, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    logger.info("=============================REQUEST BEGIN==============================================");
    logger.info("URI         :" + url);
    logger.info("Method      :" + request.getMethod());
    logger.info("Headers     :" + request.getHeaders());
    logger.info("Request body:" + requestBody);
    logger.info("=============================REQUEST END================================================");

    response = execution.execute(request, body);

    responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        //new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(response.getBody()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

    logger.info("=============================RESPONSE BEGIN=============================================");
    logger.info("Status code  : " + response.getStatusCode());
    logger.info("Status text  : " + response.getStatusText());
    logger.info("Headers      : " + response.getHeaders());
    logger.info("Response body: " + responseBody);
    logger.info("=============================RESPONSE END===============================================");

    return response;
}
```

The rest template is initialized like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));

restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections
            .singletonList(new HttpInterceptor()));
```

I have also found a similar question on StackOverflow [Why my custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with an empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023708/why-my-custom-clienthttprequestinterceptor-with-empty-response)
, but it's completely different from what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a very interesting solution but didn't get how it is even possible. The fact that I was having a difficulty to log request body but find a solution in which I have to build the completed solution with one change in RestTemplate initialization and revert back and again build the solution fixed my problem. Below is the change:

Build the completed solution without this line `new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory())`

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections
            .singletonList(new HttpInterceptor()));
```

Then revert back to its first states like this and then build the solution fixed my problem:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));

restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections
            .singletonList(new HttpInterceptor()));
```

**Note:** I have tested the solution with different inputs (i.e. Request) and it runs correctly.