# RestTemplate convertor stopped working by adding interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2 application, in which I have to log every request and response made by using Rest Template. For instance, if I have to call another service, this needs to get logged in my db. For this, I made the following changes in the Rest Template Config

```
@Configuration
@Getter
public class RestTemplateConfig {

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = template.getInterceptors();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors))
        interceptors = new ArrayList<>();

    interceptors.add(new RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor());
    template.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return template;
}
}
```

And the interceptor code is

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException {

    ResponseLoggingRepository loggingRepository = BeanUtils.getBean(ResponseLoggingRepository.class);
    ResponseLoggingEntity entity = ResponseLoggingEntity.build(request, body);
    loggingRepository.save(entity);
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    ResponseLoggingEntity.build(response, entity);
    loggingRepository.save(entity);
    return response;
}
```

}

The code works perfectly fine and I'm successfully able to log the response in the db. The issue  is when I use the rest template exchange method, I always receive the null object.

```
ResponseObject response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestObject,
                ResponseObject.class);
```

This response object is always null whenever I test. However, if I remove the interceptor from the rest template, I get proper response in my object.

I further debugged and checked for the internal converters at the time of rest template config initialization, and I'm able to see the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter which as per my understanding, is the one which converts the response from JSON to the required object. I think some additional configuration is needed so that the response object obtains the required mapping and I have no clue as to what is missing in this case? Could anyone please help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023708/why-my-custom-clienthttprequestinterceptor-with-empty-response)

Comment: See also: https://objectpartners.com/2018/03/01/log-your-resttemplate-request-and-response-without-destroying-the-body/

Comment: I tried this solution, but the error seems to be the same though the exception has started to come. ResourceAccessException is being observed. On finding more, I have found out that we can only read from the stream only once, but can't find a way to read from the stream multiple times. As mentioned in the StackOverflow link which you provided, that solution isn't working.  @AlanHay