# Spring boot rest template - HttpMessageConverter cannot convert objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

hello everyone I have a problem that I do not understand why this is happening. I am working with spring boot and deploying with Kubernetes. after a while, the restTemplate stops working and I do not know what can be the cause. this is how I am creating the restTemplate class

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate vanillaRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

after a while some of my APIs that is using restTemplate returns an error like this:

```
{
"status": 500,
"body": "{ message: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.List] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8] , cause: null }",
}
```

this is only an example. resttemplate will have a problem with many classes such as Map, String, etc when this happens. and this is how I am sending the request:

```
ResponseEntity<List> adsRes = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, List.class);
```

the weird part is when I restart the app on the server everything starts working again and the APIs have no problem at all. even the ones that returned an error.
I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415007/resttemplate-convertor-stopped-working-by-adding-interceptor) but, as you can see I have not set any interceptor or anything like that to resttemplate
thanks in advance

Comment: could you show how is calling to the endpoint?

Comment: @tino89 I just added it to the question

Comment: Do you have a sample of the response. It is likely that you are not getting a list back in the response.

Comment: @shinjw well the problem is I do not have the response, but the response is a list.

Comment: if the response is a list/map of values , then we create a class with a parameter of type list /map and use that class in resttemplate, something like below

ResponseEntity<SourceResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity,SourceResponse.class);

public class SourceResponse {
private List<String> data;
private List<Map<String, String>> value;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the way how you are calling to the endpoint by the following code

```
ResponseEntity<YourObject[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("urlService",
  YourObject[].class);

YourObject[] yourObjects= response.getBody();
List<YourObject> list = Arrays.asList(yourObjects);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but the problems is that when this happens it's not just List that it runs into a problem, restTemplate will have a problem with many classes such as Map, List, String, etc. also this API will work after I restart the server.

Comment: add into the bean you are creating "vanillaRestTemplate": MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);